# Differences between BBC TV serial and novel of Neverwhere

Tags: adaptation-comparison, neil-gaiman, neverwhere

The novel *[Neverwhere](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8404)* had a slightly unusual genesis, as the TV series came first in 1996, with the book following in 1997. Inevitably in the process of filming various compromises had to be made so that the episodes strayed from Gaiman's original vision. In this [interview](https://www.writerswrite.com/journal/neil-gaiman-3991) in 1999, Gaiman recalled:

> I would have these conversation with the producer when he'd say, "Ok,
> Neil, just to let you know we've lost this scene. This location just
> fell through." Or, "We've lost this scene; the episode is running too
> long." Or, "When filming this scene the actor broke his leg running
> down a tunnel, and you're going to have to write him out of the rest
> of it." All of which happened.

Gaiman has said in that the process of writing the book was his way of reasserting control over the story:

> Every time he would say something like that, I would say, "Its OK,
> I'll put it back in the novel." The novel, for me, was my way of
> asserting control. Saying, "No, this is what I meant." Suddenly I had
> control over the costumes again. Control over the things that I didn't
> have any control over on the TV screen. and saying "*This* is what I
> meant".

I read the novel first and saw the TV series some years later, and it appeared to me to be a rather faithful reflection of the book. Of course I was not making a detailed point-by-point comparison of the two as I was watching. What are the *major* points of difference between the two? For definiteness, I'm particularly thinking of the 1997 edition of *Neverwhere*, rather than the revised "author's preferred version" released in 2010.

Comment: Don't mention the [Beast of London](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/londoners-diary/my-cult-fantasy-was-ruined-by-a-cow-says-neil-gaiman-8521374.html) to Neil.

Comment: This explains some of the differences: https://rachfarrimond.com/2017/10/13/book-v-film-neverwhere/